# Is there any problem in using same field names in different tables then make joint query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-workbench

I have multiple tables that share the same field names and type. The tables are exactly the same except their names: `table1` and `table2`. I will `SHOW CREATE TABLE table1`:

```
CREATE TABLE `table_!` (
  `ip` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ip`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ip_UNIQUE` (`ip`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I do make joint queries like this (although the joint syntax is old, but I have been using this in the whole project, so I do not prefer to do change now):

```
SELECT COUNT(`table2`.`ip`)
FROM `ips`.`table2`, `ips`.`table1`
WHERE `table2`.`ip` = `table1`.`ip`
       AND (LOWER(`table1`.`description`) NOT LIKE 'str1%' 
             AND (LOWER(`tabl1`.`description`) LIKE '%-str2-%' 
                   OR LOWER(`table1`.`description`) LIKE '%-str3-%'
                 )
            )
       AND (LOWER(`table2`.`description`) LIKE 'str1%'
            AND LOWER(`table2`.`description`) NOT LIKE '%-str2-%' 
            AND LOWER(`table2`.`description`) NOT LIKE '%-str3-%'
           );
```

Is there any thing wrong or precaution I should take in such case?

I do not see a problem so far. Except that once I mistakenly a third table name `table3` in the `FROM` statement like this (also `table3` is similar to `table1` and `table2`).

```
FROM table1, table2, table3
```

Although I included it in the FROM, but did not use it, nor made joint relation. Just joined `table1` and `table2`.

The results that I got where different than when I removed `table3` from the FROM statement.

Comment: Nope, pretty much every single table I have has an `ID` column as a primary key. Many tables have a `NAME` column as well. As long as you prefix them with the table name or table alias you are good, as in `employee.id` as opposed to `company.id`.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with having the same column names in multiple tables. But having multiple tables with **all** the same columns is often an indicator of poor design. Why isn't this just one table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can (and will most often have) the same column names in different tables.
You should use a short alias to make references clearer:

```
SELECT count(b.ip) 
FROM   ips.table1 a, ips.table2 b 
WHERE  a.ip = b.ip 
   --  ...
```

When you add another table, table3, the output will be different as you've just added another dimension to the dataset. You also should join this table on particular columns, but again, unless there is a one to one, you'll return a different number of rows.

Comment: Thanks. What about same table names in different schemes? I forgot to mention that but I also have this case. Is there any problem?

Comment: Aliases will allow you to do schema1.tableX a, schema2.tableX b. It will then allow you to refer to a.col1 = b.col1 etc...